# Slider keeps restarting fadeInRight animation on movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slider that changes `div` properties of the different `.hero` classes  at a certain `px` range, and when the slider is `>= 300` it triggers a css `fadeInLeft` animation for `.hero2`, which works perfectly. But when then the slider is `<=100` and triggers the `fadeInRight` animation, the animation keeps restarting every time I move the slider in the `<=100` range. My `.hero3` has pretty much the same protperties as the other `.hero` classes, other than the animations.

My slider JS:

```
function activeTouchmove(e, data) {
        var event = data.event;
        var timer = data.timer;
        var touch = changedTouch(e, event);

        if (!touch) { return; }

        // Stop the interface from gesturing
        e.preventDefault();

        event.targetTouches = e.targetTouches;
        data.touch = touch;
        data.timeStamp = e.timeStamp;

        timer.kick();

        if ( $('.slider').css('left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') >= 300 )
{
    $('.hero').css('display', 'none');
    $('.hero2').css('display', 'block');
    $('.hero3').css('display', 'none');
}
else{
    $(".hero").css('display', 'block');
    $('.hero2').css('display', 'none');
    $('.hero3').css('display', 'none');
  };
  if ( $('.slider').css('left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') <= 100 )
{
    $('.hero').css('display', 'none');
    $('.hero3').css('display', 'block');
    $('.hero2').css('display', 'none');
};
```

My CSS

```
.hero3{
        animation: fadeInRight linear 0.5s;
        -webkit-animation: fadeInRight linear 0.5s;
        -moz-animation: fadeInRight linear 0.5s;
        -o-animation: fadeInRight linear 0.5s;
        -ms-animation: fadeInRight linear 0.5s;
      }

      @keyframes fadeInRight {
        0% {
           opacity: 0;
           transform: translateX(10px);
        }
        100% {
           opacity: 1;
           transform: translateX(0);
        }
     }   
     @-moz-keyframes fadeInRight {
        0% {
           opacity: 0;
           transform: translateX(10px);
        }
        100% {
           opacity: 1;
           transform: translateX(0);
        }
     }   
     @-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
        0% {
           opacity: 0;
           transform: translateX(50px);
        }
        100% {
           opacity: 1;
           transform: translateX(0);
        }
     }   
     @-o-keyframes fadeInRight {
        0% {
           opacity: 0;
           transform: translateX(10px);
        }
        100% {
           opacity: 1;
           transform: translateX(0);
        }
     }   
     @-ms-keyframes fadeInRight {
        0% {
           opacity: 0;
           transform: translateX(10px);
        }
        100% {
           opacity: 1;
           transform: translateX(0);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please only read the left value once. `const left = parseInt($('.slider').css('left')); $('.hero').toggle(left <300); $('.hero2').toggle(left>100);  $('.hero3').toggle(left<300);` or similar

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work if I replace it, I edited the JS in this thread to show the full function. Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Please click [edit] then `[<>]`  snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with HTML etc

Comment: Ah, my bad I meant to say that I'm new to JS/jQuery

Comment: Still useful to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Not sure how to provide a minimal reproducible example because the slider is not a simple one it is part of a jQuery plugin I'm using. The code you provided made my initial code more efficient but I still have the same animation problem sliding in the >100 range

Comment: I cannot guess why until I see it in action. There is some logic issue that is not easy to see with an eyeball debug - at least not for me